# why this source code is "List index out of range"

Tags: python, python-2.7

i try to create this soure code and show message "List index out of range "

```
def main():
    pass
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
temp = data[0]
i = 0
n = len(data)
while i<n:
    data[i]=data[i+1]
    i+=1
print data
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

please help me to fixed this source code

Comment: You should post the exception traceback in addition to the code. It typically contains the exact line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can solve this by changing the `while i<n` to `while i<n-1`.

**But better yet, change:**

```
i = 0
n = len(data)
while i<n:
    data[i]=data[i+1]
    i+=1
```

**To:**

```
n = len(data)
for i in range(0,n-1):
    data[i] = data[i+1]
data[n-1] = ... # Whatever you want to set the last entry to
```

**And if all you want to do is removing the first element, then simply use:**

```
temp = data.pop(0)
print data
```

Comment: Please see the first line in the answer: "you can solve this by changing the `while i<n to while i<n-1`". In addition, please see the last three lines in the answer, if all you want to do is removing the first element...

Comment: ouhh sorry brother, i'm not careful :)

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration of `while` loop, the statement `data[i+1]` tries to access the non existing index `i+1` of the list `data`.

Comment: i'm not understanding , i request  source code from you, for example

Answer (score 1):

If the value of i is 4, then, data[i+1] refers to the fifth index, which is not defined